# Relationship between analytic and holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Is every analytic function holomorphic? But not every holomorphic function is analytic?

Comment: Yes this is true

Comment: these two terminology are equivalent for a function to be in a complex plane

Comment: No, not true. "Analytic" and "holomorphic" are equivalent.

Comment: I would differ from the other comments in a nit-picking way. "Equivalence" is not the appropriate word here. Equivalence seems to suggest that analyticity and holomorphy are two different properties for a complex function, and that there is a theorem saying  that $f(z)$ is holomorphic iff it is analytic". **NO.** They are merely two different choices of terminlogy. (cf.  In graph theory people use vertex or node interchangeably.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For functions of a single complex variable, a function being analytic is equivalent to it being holomorphic. That is, Analytic $\implies$ Holomorphic, and Holomorphic $\implies$ Analytic.

Up till recently, I would have agreed with P Vanchinathan's comment, that the two are merely synonyms of each other, but I no longer think that's the best way of looking at it. Of course these are merely words, and so one can define them however one wants, but a good way (and from what I understand, a fairly standard way) to define them is a complex function being "analytic" at a point means that it has a convergent Taylor Series on some open disk centered at that point. In contrast, a function being "holomorphic" at a point simply means that it is differentiable on some open disk centered at that point. With these two definitions they are no longer mere synonyms, but (amazingly) they are equivalent. I think [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) says it well:

> Though the term analytic function is often used interchangeably with "holomorphic function", the word "analytic" is defined in a broader sense to denote any function (real, complex, or of more general type) that can be written as a convergent power series in a neighborhood of each point in its domain. The fact that all holomorphic functions are complex analytic functions, and vice versa, is a [major theorem in complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functions_are_analytic).

Comment: This. Analyticity and holomorphicity are two conceptually different properties. It's rather easy to see that an analytic function is holomorphic, but the other direction is an amazing theorem.