# Why does analyticity require differentiability in a open neighbourhood?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

For a complex function $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ to be analytic at a point $p \in \mathbb C$, it is given in literature it should be differentiable at $p$ as well as in an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$.

But I don't understand why it has to differentiable in this open neighbourhood. I have searched multiple times without success.

Comment: That is a definition. What exactly is your question?

Comment: May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244769/relationship-between-analytic-and-holomorphic) is helpful

Comment: Peter's got it right here; your definition provided is not actually the definition of analytic, but the definition of *holomorphic*. It's one of the big theorems of complex analysis that holomorphicity is equivalent to analyticity, which is why you probably see literature using them interchangeably.

Comment: analyticity always (as we could have such in real variables or Banach algebra or even p-adic context, so in other words as long as we have an algebra structure with some notion of convergence) means Taylor series convergence and that means an open neighbourhood; it is a remarkable and extremely powerful tool that in the complex case differentiability in an open set implies analyticity as that is far from being true in most other contexts where both notions make sense

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I wanted to ask what would have happened if for analyticity at some point, the function is required to be derivable at that point, not on its open neighbourhood.